# What exactly is BlueMix in layman's terms?

Tags: ibm-cloud

How exactly would someone define BlueMix to an engineering major with little to no knowledge in Comp. Sci?

Comment: This kind of question is not suitable for stack overflow. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [on-topic section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix is a fully managed cloud service so all of the operations activities such as maintenance, availability, upgrades are part of the Bluemix service, so users don't have to worry about setting up their own infrastructure or installing software.

Bluemix makes it easy for application developers to write applications as it is a polygot environment that supports many different languages and runtimes.

Applications in Bluemix can easily be scaled as needed leveraging the elasticity of the cloud. There are over 100 services available in Bluemix (both IBM and 3rd party services) which can be tied together to make robust applications and also to implement a microservices architecture.

Bluemix cloud services are available as part of the public multi-tenant cloud offering which runs on softlayer. There are also dedicated and local Bluemix cloud offerings available for users who don't want to use the public cloud or want to combine the different offerings to create a hybrid cloud.

Answer (score 0):

it is a platform that lets you build, run, deploy applications via cloud. moreover, it handles multiple languages

Answer (score 0):

Check Bluemix Overview topic in the docs: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/index.html